# Fix 'experimantalDecorator error' in Nuxt.Js projec despite being I fixed 'experimantalDecorator : true'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have used Nuxt.Js in my latest project.
I used decoratr like '@' in .ts file and error message occurred on '@'.
My code is below.

```
    import { Component, Vue } from "nuxt-property-decorator";

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue {
    greeting:string = ''
    message:string = 'world'
    get hello(){
        return this.greeting + ' ' + this.message + '!'
    }
}
```

and error message is below.

```
Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.
```

So I checked the relevant part in tsconfig.json and it's already  'experimentalDecorators:true'.
And I checked jsconfig.json but I couldn't find out 'experimentalDecorators' in my file.

my jsconfig.json like below.

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "~~/*": ["./*"],
      "@@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".nuxt", "dist"]
}
```

Actually, I run the code and no compile error occurred.
So I might think its just warning but my client is really strict.
I have to fix the issue.
Could anyone advise me?

Comment: Can you provide a GitHub link that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'm not good at using Github, but I will try.
I will provide a Github link when I finish make the repositoly.